# Select and display certain rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to just get the `DataGridView` to display **ONLY** the rows of the last name entered. From there I can build the rest of my program but I hit a speed-bump. I saw that patch of code that's in my `Submit_Button_Click` event online but it doesn't work. It breaks at the else bracket. Any advice?
I'm sorry I'm new to this but if I learn it once I'll remember forever.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string LastName;
    //string FirstName;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.aRMORERS_TableAdapter.Fill(this.armorersDataSet._ARMORERS_);
    }

    private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LastName = LastName_TextBox.Text;
        //FirstName = FirstName_TextBox.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == LastName)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i imagine dgtest is a datagrid

Comment: Yes you are right. Fixed that issue thank you. but now it just breaks

Comment: From what I was told it didn't work because I have columns with money (decimal) values. I was advised to call a query using parameters.

Comment: Interesting. I think the advice you've been given is sound. I usually filter my data and rebind in my projects. but passing query parameters to the database should be ok too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use filtering instead of loop.

Try to replace code in your `Submit_Button_Click` event handler by following:

```
    private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lastName = LastName_TextBox.Text;
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
             string.Format("Field_Name = '{0}'", lastName);
    }
```

Where "Field_Name" should be replaced by your column name.

P.S. If you do not need exact matching of the last name, you can use LIKE operator with wildcard characters to filter using patterns "Contains" and "Starts with" (or "Ends with").

Contains all characters in textbox: `string.Format("Field_Name LIKE '*{0}*'", lastName);`

Starts with characters in textbox: `string.Format("Field_Name LIKE '{0}*'", lastName);`

Ends with: `string.Format("Field_Name LIKE '*{0}'", lastName);`